# Parse list of Json strings in a dataframe by converting the column into rows using pyspark?

Tags: python, json, apache-spark, parsing, pyspark

```
//Input
df = [ 
      ('{"id":10, "number" : ["1.1", "1.2", "1.3"]}',),
      ('{"id":20, "number" : ["2.1", "2.2", "2.3"]}',),
       ]
```

//Desired output in a dataframe

| id | number |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | 1.1 |
| 10 | 1.2 |
| 10 | 1.3 |
| 20 | 2.1 |
| 20 | 2.2 |
| 20 | 2.3 |

I tried withColumn but was only able to split it into 2 columns

```
df.withColumn("n",from_json(col("_1"),Sch)).select("n.*")
```

How can I get the 2nd column to split into rows and the first column to be repeated for each number in pyspark?

Any help would be greatly appreciated! TIA!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `explode` here eg

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df.withColumn("n",F.from_json(F.col("_1"),Sch))\
  .select("n.id",F.explode("n.number").alias("number"))
```

Full reproducible example included below:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import types as T

df = [ 
      ('{"id":10, "number" : ["1.1", "1.2", "1.3"]}',),
      ('{"id":20, "number" : ["2.1", "2.2", "2.3"]}',),
       ]

Sch = T.StructType([
    T.StructField("id",T.IntegerType(),True),
    T.StructField("number",T.ArrayType(T.StringType()),True)
])
df = sparkSession.createDataFrame(df)
df.show()

df.withColumn("n",F.from_json(F.col("_1"),Sch))\
  .select("n.id",F.explode("n.number").alias("number"))\
  .show(truncate=False)
```

**outputs**

```
+-------------------------------------------+
|_1                                         |
+-------------------------------------------+
|{"id":10, "number" : ["1.1", "1.2", "1.3"]}|
|{"id":20, "number" : ["2.1", "2.2", "2.3"]}|
+-------------------------------------------+

+----+------+
|n.id|number|
+----+------+
|10  |1.1   |
|10  |1.2   |
|10  |1.3   |
|20  |2.1   |
|20  |2.2   |
|20  |2.3   |
+----+------+
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: It worked! Thank you. One change: df = spark.createDataFrame(df)